# How Can a User Edit a Config Value in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have created a mailable class in Laravel 5.3 and have set the global variables for the name and return email in config/mail.php. I would like to have these values be editable by an admin user, without the need for them to go to the config file or edit the .env. How do I do this?

Comment: You can put default value of config as second argument. I don't think you can edit it

Comment: You need to change them on the fly per execution or permanent?

Comment: @AvikAghajanyan Ideally, it would be semi-permanent, so that the admin can change it and it would be applied to all e-mails until it is changed again.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such functionality in Laravel, so you'll need to use one of the packages for that, for example [this one](https://github.com/larapack/config-writer)

Answer (score 0):

You can write such helper function to edit .env

```
function saveConfiguration($values, $configFilename = '.env') {
        if (empty($values) || !is_array($values)) {
            return false;
        }

        $envFile = base_path($configFilename);
        if (!File::exists($envFile)) {
            $existingConfig = [];
        } else {
            $existingConfig = file($envFile);
        }

        $configs = [];
        foreach ($existingConfig as $config) {
            if (!empty(str_replace(' ', '', $config))) {
                $config = str_replace([
                    "\r",
                    "\n"
                ], ['', ''], $config);
                $configParts = explode('=', $config, 2);
                if (!empty($configParts[1])) {
                    if (!array_key_exists($configParts[0], $values)) {
                        $configs[] = $configParts[0].'='.$configParts[1];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
            $value = str_replace('"', '\"', $value);
            if (strpos($values[$key], ' ') !== false) {
                $configs[] = $key.'="'.$value.'"';
            } else {
                $configs[] = $key.'='.$value;
            }
        }

        File::put($envFile, implode("\n", $configs));

        return true;
    }
```

Then use it to save in .env, and configure your config/mail.php to use credentials from there